# I have a page where it loads a map. When I open fancybox to show an image, it seem to be "cut off" by the map

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a page where it loads a map. When I open fancybox to show an image, it seem to be "cut off" by the map.

Image showing OK when no scrolling:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW5XU.jpg]

But when I scroll down a bit, the image cut off:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/DTmx5.jpg]

If I remove the map:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/TmSQX.jpg]

I've tried Z-INDEX an so, and the problem persists. There's a live example here: http://llegoelfinde.com.ar/events/mameluco-fiesta-rock/

Comment: It worked fine for me.  The Fancybox actually seems to remove the scrollbars in my browser, so there's no possibility of error.

Comment: I've updated the post. The issue is on Chrome and happend when you scroll a bit and then click in the thumbnail. In FF and IE is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Grab current scroll position (don't forget horizontal axis!).
Set overflow to hidden (probably want to retain previous overflow value).
Scroll document to stored scroll position with scrollTo().
Then when you're ready to allow scrolling again, undo all that.

```
// lock scroll position, but retain settings for later
  var scrollPosition = [
    self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
    self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
  ];
  var html = jQuery('html'); // it would make more sense to apply this to body, but IE7 won't have that
  html.data('scroll-position', scrollPosition);
  html.data('previous-overflow', html.css('overflow'));
  html.css('overflow', 'hidden');
  window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);


  // un-lock scroll position
  var html = jQuery('html');
  var scrollPosition = html.data('scroll-position');
  html.css('overflow', html.data('previous-overflow'));
  window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1])
```